# sql query via PHP always skip the first row

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am facing a strange issue and I don't know where this issue is coming from. I have a mySQL database called `weather-app` with a table `cities` on that table I have a list of all US towns and cities (columns `city` and `population`).

Let me run a query directly on my SQL db:

```
SELECT * FROM cities WHERE city LIKE 'boston' ORDER BY population DESC
```

As a result I am getting

```
1840000455  Boston  MA  4637537
1840013902  Boston  GA  1315
1840024721  Boston  VA  674
1840026471  Boston  PA  236
1840009492  Boston  IN  130
1840026800  Boston  KY  89
```

The same query directly via my PHP is giving me that:

```
1840013902  Boston  GA  1315
1840024721  Boston  VA  674
1840026471  Boston  PA  236
1840009492  Boston  IN  130
1840026800  Boston  KY  89
```

It's doing this for every queries and only for the first line.

My code:

**index.html**

```
<body>
    <?php require_once("config/db.php")?>
    <h2>Weather</h2>
    <input type="text" name="city-search" class="city-search" id="city-search">
    <ul class="result">
    </ul>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/app.js"></script>
</body>
```

**app.js**

```
search.addEventListener("keyup", e =>{
    let city = search.value;
    if(city != ""){
        loadCities(city);
    }
});

const loadCities = (city) => {
    $.ajax({
        url: "config/fetch-cities.php",
        method: "GET",
        data: {
            query: city
        },
        success: function(data){
            results.innerHTML = data;
        }
    });
}
```

**fetch-cities.php**

```
<?php 
require("db.php");

if(isset($_GET["query"])){

    $search = $_GET["query"];

    $results = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM cities WHERE city LIKE '{$search}%' 
    ORDER BY population DESC");
} 

$results->execute();
$row_count =$results->fetchColumn();

foreach ($results as $row) {
    echo $row["city"] . "-" . $row["population"] ."<br/>";
}
?>
```

[result of `http://localhost:8080/weather-app/config/fetch-cities.php?query=Boston`:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/81m92.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. It might be helpful to review the Network payloads from the browser, this can be seen under the Network Tab. What are the results when you do  it manually, navigate to `fetch-cities.php?query=Boston`

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, I will have to learn more about injections. I went to `http://localhost:8080/weather-app/config/fetch-cities.php?query=Boston`and I still getting the wrong result (skipped the first line)

Comment: **WARNING**: When using PDO you should be using [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) with placeholder values and supply any user data as separate arguments. In this code you have potentially severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). Never use string interpolation or concatenation and instead use [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) and never put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or any user data directly in your query. Refer to [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) for general guidance and advice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This line:

```
$row_count =$results->fetchColumn();
```

doesn't return a row count. It returns first column from the first row of the resultset and moves the pointer to the next row, which is why you're not getting the first row in your `foreach` later on.